# cURL login session

Tags: session, cookies, curl, authentication

I need to use a website as a logged user. The code below does the job well, however it has to log in every time the script is called. I'd like to log in just once and from then on use session cookies.

```
$c=curl_init();
$url='http://www.site.com/login/';              
$opt=array(CURLOPT_URL=>$url,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR=>'cookie.txt',CURLOPT_POST=>1,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>'username=usr123&password=pass&submit='); //submit=1 works too
curl_setopt_array($c,$opt);
curl_exec($c);
$url='http://www.site.com/next';
$opt2=array(CURLOPT_URL=>$url,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1);
curl_setopt_array($c,$opt2);
$out=curl_exec($c);
echo $out;
curl_close($c);
```

I tried using session, but for some reason the user login doesn't work.

```
$c=curl_init();
$ag='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)';
if(!file_exists('cookie.txt')){
  $url='http://www.site.com/login/';
  $opt=array(CURLOPT_URL=>$url,
  CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR=>'cookie.txt',
  CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE=>'cookie.txt',
  CURLOPT_POST=>0,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>1,
  CURLOPT_USERPWD=>'usr123:pass,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>0,
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>$ag);
  curl_setopt_array($c,$opt);
  curl_exec($c);
}  

$url='http://www.site.com/next/';
$opt2=array(CURLOPT_URL=>$url,
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR=>'cookie.txt',
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE=>'cookie.txt',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>1,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>2,
CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>$ag);
curl_setopt_array($c,$opt2);
$out=curl_exec($c);
echo $out;
curl_close($c);
```

Comment: It looks like the site is using HTTP auth, correct?  Technically you don't need to "login", just send the `USERPWD` with your first request no matter where it needs to go.  If the site is doing something special with the login and then setting a cookie, its difficult to help without seeing how the site works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I solved the problem. Solution is added to the original post

Comment: @bukzor: all right, added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
if(!file_exists('cookie.txt')){
  $url='http://www.site.com/login/';                         

  $opt=array(CURLOPT_URL=>$url,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR=>'cookie.txt',CURLOPT_POST=>1,
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>'username=usr123&password=pass&submit=');
  curl_setopt_array($c,$opt);
  curl_exec($c);
}
$url='http://www.site.com/next';
$opt2=array(CURLOPT_URL=>$url,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR=>'cookie.txt',CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE=>'cookie.txt',
      CURLOPT_POST=>0,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1,CURLOPT_USERPWD=>'usr123:pass');
curl_setopt_array($c,$opt2);
$output=curl_exec($c);
echo $output;
```