# curl login, session cookie in two passes

Tags: php, curl

I try to login with curl to a SSL secured website but somehow I don't get it right.

The first curl connection retrieves the login form. An SSL issue in the beginning is resolved now. The fields used for authentication and all hidden fields are identified and used for the following POST. The cookie file is defined and the jar to read from as well. The cookie file is accessible and gets updated with each login attempt. A session cookie is successfully set by curl. The HTTPHEADER is removed to stop the request from hitting the 100 Continue wall. Curl is configured to follow up and to send a referer. 
However, I still cannot find where the script gets stuck. Neither Curl nor PHP issue any error messages or warnings.

Here is the shortened script:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,       1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,        1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,   1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,    array('Expect:')); // remove Expect header to avoid 100 Continue situations
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,     'Mozilla [abbreviated]');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,        dirname(__FILE__).'/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,    dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.hq.txt'); // write cookies
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,     dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.hq.txt'); // read cookies
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,           'https://the_url.jsp');

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$error= curl_error($ch);
if(!empty($error))
    echo '<p>'.$error.'</p>';
else
    echo '<p>ok</p>';
```

Now the script reads the form, fills in the credentials and POSTs it back using the same curl_init handle:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,       1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $options);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$error=curl_error($ch);
```

But all I get back is the same form again and the same session cookie or a new one depending on the CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION setting.

When I log in manually I notice that there are two more cookies set: LtpaToken and LtpaToken2 but I never see them appearing in the request headers printed by the script. 
Manually submitting the form works even without Javascript aktivated. So there cannot be some JS magic modifying the form data under the hood before submitting it.
Obviously I am missing something here. Any ideas where I can look further?

Solved: Finally the issue was due to an encoding issue in the POST. 
Initially the POST data was created from an array with http_build_query(). 
Now the POST data is simply concatenated and both keys and values are urlencoded separately:

```
    $options.=urlencode($fieldName).'='.urlencode($element->getAttribute('value'));
```

Comment: To confirm that JS is not modifying, you should inspect the POST request in browser using tools like firebug, inbuilt developer consoles.

Comment: I have deviated the request to a page that displays the complete $_REQUEST array and there is nothing that looks different from the orginal form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Finally the issue was due to an encoding issue in the POST. Initially the POST data was created from an array with http_build_query(). Now the POST data is simply concatenated and both keys and values are urlencoded separately:

```
$options.=urlencode($fieldName).'='.urlencode($element->getAttribute('value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

See below url:--

[cURL login session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515145/curl-login-session)

and try this:-

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

```
<?php

 echo curl_grab_page("https://www.example.net/login.php", "https://www.example.net/", "username=foo&password=bar", "true",  "null", "false");

// $url = page to POST data
// $ref_url = tell the server which page you came from (spoofing)
// $login = true will make a clean cookie-file.
// $proxy = proxy data
// $proxystatus = do you use a proxy ? true/false

function
curl_grab_page($url,$ref_url,$data,$login,$proxy,$proxystatus){
    if($login == 'true') {
        $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
        fclose($fp);
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    if ($proxystatus == 'true') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref_url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($ch); // execute the curl command
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($ch);
    unset($ch);
}
```