# Improving script efficiency and reliability

Tags: bash, performance, shell, curl, gnu-parallel

I have this sample code which basically repeats ~20k times. The only thing that changes is the id= in the address and in the echo command line. The id= in the address and the id= in the echo line always correspond. I am running this script on a MAC if that is of any importance.

I would like to improve this script if possible to make it more reliable. Sometimes I either lose connectivity or the session to the server is closed and I am required to log in again but the script keeps running oblivious of the situation. I would like the script to pause if for some reason that happens.

Also after the `open` command is called, sometimes the server takes longer to responds but the `osascript` command forces the tab to close after the `sleep 2` command has elapsed. This puts me in a position where I am not sure if the server actually took into account the url. Increasing the sleep time is not very reliable. What could be done on that front?

```
[...]
open 'https://domaineName.com/admin/?adsess=dhnchf6ghd5shak4Dghtfffvw&app=core&module=members&controller=members&do=spam&id=1&status=1' -g
sleep 2
osascript -e 'tell window 1 of application "Safari"
close (tabs where index < (get index of current tab))
end'
echo "done id=1"

open 'https://domaineName.com/admin/?adsess=dhnchf6ghd5shak4Dghtfffvw&app=core&module=members&controller=members&do=spam&id=5&status=1' -g
sleep 2
osascript -e 'tell window 1 of application "Safari"
close (tabs where index < (get index of current tab))
end'
echo "done id=5"
[...]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is unclear, but if you are running into problems with tabs closing before the command is sent, it sounds like you are running into problems with the asynchronous execution of background processes. You can save the *process ID* (`PID`) of each call you need to executed in order (with the special shell variable `$!`) and tell your script to `wait` until that process completes before moving on. E.g. after `open` and `osascript` you could write `wait $!`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for your comment. What is unclear? I'll gladly edit the question to clarify. The tab closing before time is something that happens rarely but when it does then I need to stop the script manually and check if the command was taken into account by the server. Would you mind integrating your suggestions in the code. Sorry I'm not a programmer.

Comment: The url must be opened with safari? If not, you can replace `open` with `curl` to perform the communication with server. Then, the `sleep` and `osascript` it not necessary.

Comment: @Hanuman "*Also sometimes the page takes longer to load but the script forces the tab to close before the command has been fully submitted to the server*" is the part that is unclear to me. Do the first *X number* of calls work, and then they start failing as of *call Y*? The crux of the question I understand, exactly where and when the problem appears is a bit of a mystery.

Comment: @alijandro I think it must be opened in a browser because I need to be logged in and authenticated in the administrative panel.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The `osascript` command forces the tab to the left to close once `osascript` is called. That happens no matter what after the `sleep 2` command elapses. If for some reason the page has not fully loaded (or the server hasn't answered to the requested url) then it will close the tab since the script doesn't know if the page loaded successfully or not (or the server answered or not). This could happen for many reasons one being that the server is overloaded and not answering within the 2 seconds requested in the `sleep 2` command

Comment: What is your actual overall objective? What are you really trying too achieve?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ban ~20k user accounts from a forum which are in fact spam accounts. The administrative panel of the forum does not allow flagging as spam more than one account at time. Which is ridiculous if you ask me. I do not have access to the database which of course would have been my first choice, hence the script.

Comment: So you don't actually need to *see* anything in Safari? So you could use **curl** and **GNU Parallel** and get the job done about 100x faster...

Comment: @MarkSetchell I need to be authenticated. Once authenticated a session will be set. Is that possible with curl? If so how can I implement it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22263825/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks. Would you mind adapting it to my case? I'm not a coder but I am able to then replicate it if I know how it works with my code. Thanks and sorry if this sounds too demanding.

Comment: There are plenty of folk on StackOverflow who do **curl** much better than me, so I have added the `curl` tag to your question to see if anyone can help. Once you get curl working for a single user account, it should be possible to use **GNU Parallel** with a whole list of accounts and get it all running very fast and reliably.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ok thanks. So far my attempts have been unsuccessful. Wait and see for someone to chime in.

Comment: I cannot experiment with logging in to your server as I don't have an account, but here is how to do it... https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138681

Comment: @MarkSetchell That did create the cookie file with the session. Not sure how to then use the session in the code...

Comment: You just add `-b cookiefile` to subsequent requests.

Comment: @MarkSetchell How? This is the type of link required for the user to be tagged as spammer once authenticated: `https://domaineName.com/admin/?adsess=dhnchf6ghd5shak4Dghtfffvw&app=core&module=members&controller=members&do=spam&id=5&status=1` . The session is the `dhnchf6ghd5shak4Dghtff‌​fvw` part - Sorry but I'm just a total noob at this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a script that checks if the main script (**lets say main.sh**) is currently running on the server `(like ps -ef|grep main.sh|grep -v grep)`

Check the above output and then execute main.sh inside this script.

This way there is no need for using delay/sleep commands.

Comment: Save the `grep -v`, and hence a child process, with : `ps -ef|grep '[m]ain.sh'` (it does not matter which character the `[ ]` go around).

Comment: Not sure I understand. There is no script running ON the server. The script is running from my laptop. Mind to elaborate?

Comment: @Hanuman, let me know if there is any batch scheduler that is running the script on your  Mac, i am not adept in mac so not sure. If there is one, then can you check which script is currently running. If all i said above is true, then write a script that checks the scheduler for current running scripts and if you find your script is running, then just put `echo "the script is alraedy running"` , otherwise execute the script again. Hope this clarifies the doubt.

Comment: @LohitGupta. There is no script scheduler. I am running the script manually as this is a one time script.